# "Variable binding depth exceeds max-specpdl-size" error with basic emacs calc example

Tags: emacs, org-mode, calc

I'm trying to replicate the main example for the embedded use of emacs calc. (https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Embedded-Mode-Overview.html) So I have the line `ln(ln(x))` with an empty line before and after.

But as result of `C-x * e` I get: `calc-embedded: Variable binding depth exceeds max-specpdl-size`.

I'm using GNU Emacs 27.1 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.30, cairo version 1.16.0) of 2022-01-24, modified by Debian under Ubuntu jammy. I tried in org-mode and in *scratch*.

max-specpld-size is 1840. That should be enough.

Any suggestion on how to make embedded calc work?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to recreate the same error by activating `calc-embedded` in a scratch buffer and killing that buffer.  Then, when opening a new scratch buffer and trying to start `calc-embedded`, the `calc-embedded-info` array is populated with bad buffers and it goes into infinite recursion.

So, to fix it I set the info to `nil`: `(setq calc-embedded-info nil)`, to start from a clean slate.

I think this should normally be handled by the `kill-buffer-query-functions` hook, but I'm not sure this is set in `calc-embedded`.